# convert io.StringIO to io.BytesIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, io, stream

**original question:** i got a [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) object, how can i convert it into [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)?

**update:** The more general question is, how to convert a binary (encoded) [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) object into decoded [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) object in python3?

the naive approach i got is:

```
import io
sio = io.StringIO('wello horld')
bio = io.BytesIO(sio.read().encode('utf8'))
print(bio.read())  # prints b'wello horld'
```

is there more efficient and elegant way of doing this? the above code just reads everything into memory, encodes it instead of streaming the data in chunks.

for example, for the reverse question (`BytesIO` -> `StringIO`) there exist a class - [io.TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) which does exactly that (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51256866/7438048))

Comment: Does “more elegant” include implementing it yourself without such a bulk copy?

Comment: i hope there is something better, if not that should be better than naive approach so yes.

Comment: Please be aware that in the original question you ask for BytesIO -> StringIO and in the update StringIO -> BytesIO. And the example continues with BytesIO -> StringIO.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's interesting that though the question might seem reasonable, it's not that easy to figure out a practical reason why I would need to convert a `StringIO` into a `BytesIO`. Both are basically buffers and you usually need only one of them to make some additional manipulations either with the bytes or with the text.

I may be wrong, but I think your question is actually how to use a `BytesIO` instance when some code to which you want to pass it expects a text file.

In which case, it is a common question and the solution is [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module.

The two usual cases of using it are the following:

#### Compose a File Object to Read

```
In [16]: import codecs, io

In [17]: bio = io.BytesIO(b'qwe\nasd\n')

In [18]: StreamReader = codecs.getreader('utf-8')  # here you pass the encoding

In [19]: wrapper_file = StreamReader(bio)

In [20]: print(repr(wrapper_file.readline()))
'qwe\n'

In [21]: print(repr(wrapper_file.read()))
'asd\n'

In [26]: bio.seek(0)
Out[26]: 0

In [27]: for line in wrapper_file:
    ...:     print(repr(line))
    ...:
'qwe\n'
'asd\n'
```

#### Compose a File Object to Write To

```
In [28]: bio = io.BytesIO()

In [29]: StreamWriter = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')  # here you pass the encoding

In [30]: wrapper_file = StreamWriter(bio)

In [31]: print('жаба', 'цап', file=wrapper_file)

In [32]: bio.getvalue()
Out[32]: b'\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x86\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\n'

In [33]: repr(bio.getvalue().decode('utf-8'))
Out[33]: "'жаба цап\\n'"
```

Comment: One reason you need a `BytesIO` instead of a `StringIO` can be to upload an in-memory file to a S3 bucket using the `upload_fileobj`. More info [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_fileobj)

Comment: `OutputStreamWriter` is an equivalent of the requested wrapper in `Java`. As of early 2021 Github search yields 1M usages of it. That's for the "practicality" of it.

Comment: very funny strung 'Жаба цап гадюку' =)

Comment: A full example using StringIO and BytesIO: bytes_io = io.BytesIO(string_io.getvalue().encode())

Answer (score 4):

[@foobarna answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55961119/952437) can be improved by inheriting some `io` base-class

```py
import io
sio = io.StringIO('wello horld')


class BytesIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader):
    """Wrap a buffered bytes stream over TextIOBase string stream."""

    def __init__(self, text_io_buffer, encoding=None, errors=None, **kwargs):
        super(BytesIOWrapper, self).__init__(text_io_buffer, **kwargs)
        self.encoding = encoding or text_io_buffer.encoding or 'utf-8'
        self.errors = errors or text_io_buffer.errors or 'strict'

    def _encoding_call(self, method_name, *args, **kwargs):
        raw_method = getattr(self.raw, method_name)
        val = raw_method(*args, **kwargs)
        return val.encode(self.encoding, errors=self.errors)

    def read(self, size=-1):
        return self._encoding_call('read', size)

    def read1(self, size=-1):
        return self._encoding_call('read1', size)

    def peek(self, size=-1):
        return self._encoding_call('peek', size)


bio = BytesIOWrapper(sio)
print(bio.read())  # b'wello horld'
```

Comment: UTF8 is not always single byte. this is incorrect: `BytesIOWrapper(io.StringIO('אבגד')).read(1)`
returns two bytes: `b'\xd7\x90'`

Comment: @ShmulikA, yeah, it returns 1 "character". To really return 1 byte "intermediate" buffer should be implemented

Answer (score 3):

It could be a generally useful tool to convert a character stream into a byte stream, so here goes:

```
import io

class EncodeIO(io.BufferedIOBase):
  def __init__(self,s,e='utf-8'):
    self.stream=s               # not raw, since it isn't
    self.encoding=e
    self.buf=b""                # encoded but not yet returned
  def _read(self,s): return self.stream.read(s).encode(self.encoding)
  def read(self,size=-1):
    b=self.buf
    self.buf=b""
    if size is None or size<0: return b+self._read(None)
    ret=[]
    while True:
      n=len(b)
      if size<n:
        b,self.buf=b[:size],b[size:]
        n=size
      ret.append(b)
      size-=n
      if not size: break
      b=self._read(min((size+1024)//2,size))
      if not b: break
    return b"".join(ret)
  read1=read
```

Obviously `write` could be defined symmetrically to decode input and send it to the underlying stream, although then you have to deal with having enough bytes for only part of a character.

Comment: @ShmulikA: Loops forever, even; edited.  I forgot the `break` when I rewrote the buffering (before posting).

Answer (score 2):

As some pointed out, you need to do the encoding/decoding yourself.

However, you can achieve this in an elegant way - implementing your own `TextIOWrapper` for `string => bytes`.

Here is such a sample:

```
class BytesIOWrapper:
    def __init__(self, string_buffer, encoding='utf-8'):
        self.string_buffer = string_buffer
        self.encoding = encoding

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.string_buffer, attr)

    def read(self, size=-1):
        content = self.string_buffer.read(size)
        return content.encode(self.encoding)

    def write(self, b):
        content = b.decode(self.encoding)
        return self.string_buffer.write(content)
```

Which produces an output like this:

```
In [36]: bw = BytesIOWrapper(StringIO("some lengt˙˚hyÔstring in here"))

In [37]: bw.read(15)
Out[37]: b'some lengt\xcb\x99\xcb\x9ahy\xc3\x94'

In [38]: bw.tell()
Out[38]: 15

In [39]: bw.write(b'ME')
Out[39]: 2

In [40]: bw.seek(15)
Out[40]: 15

In [41]: bw.read()
Out[41]: b'MEring in here'
```

Hope it clears your thoughts!

Comment: `read(size)` must read <= `size` bytes. However, `len(bw.read(15))` is `18`.

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski Indeed. That is because you say "read 15 bytes" when in fact it reads "15 string characters", which happens some of them to be 2 bytes long, hence the "18 length". I didn't say it was perfect, but at least it's not breaking the encoding (by splitting a valid utf-8 char in 2).
That is a sample, which can be improved by adding more checking or more methods (readline, context manager, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same need, so I created an `EncodedStreamReader` class in the `nr.utils.io` package. It also solves the issue with actually reading the number of bytes requested instead of the number of characters from the wrapped stream.

```
$ pip install 'nr.utils.io>=0.1.0,<1.0.0'
```

Example usage:

```
import io
from nr.utils.io.readers import EncodedStreamReader
fp = EncodedStreamReader(io.StringIO('ä'), 'utf-8')
assert fp.read(1) == b'\xc3'
assert fp.read(1) == b'\xa4'
```

Answer (score -1):

`bio` from your example is `_io.BytesIO` class object.
You have used 2 times the `read()` function.

I came up with `bytes` conversion and one `read()` method:

```
sio = io.StringIO('wello horld')
b = bytes(sio.read(), encoding='utf-8')
print(b)
```

But the second variant should be even faster:

```
sio = io.StringIO('wello horld')
b = sio.read().encode()
print(b)
```