# Uploading a plotly html to azure blob: change string to bytes

Tags: python, azure-functions, plotly, azure-blob-storage

I create a html in plotly and want to upload it to azure blob storage.

```
fig.write_html("C:/test.html")
```

How to write it in memory, so that I can upload it?

When using

```
html_file = io.StringIO()
fig.write_html(html_file)
```

I get the error on upload, that is not bytes.

When normally uploading html strings I use

```
blob_client.upload_blob(html.encode('utf-8') ,blob_type="BlockBlob", overwrite=True, content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='text/html'))
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

**EDIT:**

I need to write it into memory, since I am using it in an azure function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my system able to upload the plotly html file I taken the sample dataframe

try with this code

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

data = {'Product': ['Desktop Computer','Tablet','Printer','Laptop'],
        'Price': [850,200,150,1300]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Product', 'Price'])
fig = px.bar(df, x='Product', y='Price')
pio.write_html(fig, file='output.html')

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("Connection string")
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")
path="C:\\Users \\output.html"

with open(path, "rb") as data:
    blob_clientnew = container_client.get_blob_client("output.html")
    blob_clientnew.upload_blob(data)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I edited my question: I am using Azure-functions, that is why I try not to save to disk, rather use the file in memory. I am not that familiar with that topic, that is why I used this for a parquet file in an azure function:       
    `parquet_file = io.BytesIO()
    df_all.to_parquet(parquet_file,  engine='pyarrow')
    parquet_file.seek(0)  # change the stream position back to the beginning after writing

    blob_client.upload_blob(data=parquet_file, overwrite=True)`

Comment: Instead of saving file locally ,You want to save in stream and upload it to blob .Correct me if I  am wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying.

Comment: But as you mentioned `write_html ` saves the html file locally

Comment: But writing it to StringIO goes without saving it locally. But how to convert it to bytes?

Comment: Please refer this SO Thread :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889474/convert-io-stringio-to-io-bytesio

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you